# Свободное падение

Tags: java, android, разработка-игр

Мне вот интересно стало, во flash играх вот как [эта](http://best-flash.com/load/3-1-0-173#.TxsIKaXJxc9), спрайта находится в состоянии свободноего падения, как это можно сделать в java ?

Comment: Это не похоже на свободное падение, ускорения не ощущается.

Comment: как по мне, там больше "физики", чем падения, а про падение - есть формулы, есть константы, по ним все считается...

Comment: Объясните как это делается, я понимаю что там физика есть, мне интересно как сделать что бы картинка вот так вот падала.

Comment: я не флешер, но предполагаю, что там есть скелетная физика, которая в общем и обсчитывание все эти движения

Comment: как это реализовать в java игре? а не как оно работает в флеш

Comment: надо физический движок для джава игры искать... есть еще вариант, но его не предлагаю =)

Comment: Так что надо: как рисовать или как считать координаты от времени ?

Comment: движок не подходит, чется самому разобраться как делать, с нуля

avp, не знаю что надо, нужно что бы было как в флеш игре, ну или хотя бы похожее.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Такая кукла, называется ragdoll. Обработкой ее движения занимается физ.движок. В спрайтовых играх широко используется Box2D. Он портирован под множество языков программирования, в том числе и под Java (в виде [JBox2D](http://jbox2d.org/)).

Как он устроен всегда можно подсмотреть в исходниках, благо они открыты. Самому писать с нуля такие вещи нет смысла, если только вы не хотите научиться писать физдвижки. Для игрового проекта же, всегда лучше использовать готовые отлаженные продукты.

Comment: Crytek c тобой не согласен =)

Comment: т.е. самому такое написать за пару дней никак? только готовый движок?

Comment: чуть чаем не подавился "за пару дней"

Comment: Понятное дело что компании уровня Crytek, Id, Epic Games могут инвестировать в собственную разработку middleware. Под "самому писать с нуля" я подразумевал именно студентов, разработчиков-одиночек, мелкие инди-студии. Достаточно подсчитать сколько средств уйдет на разработку движка, а за сколько можно лицензировать чужой (да еще и с техподдержкой, несколькими годами тестирования и дебага)

Comment: @Nofate, я же пошутил =)

Comment: @Gorets, да понятно. Я больше для топикстартера пояснял.